# Formik not working with Next JS 14 App Directory

Tags: typescript, next.js, formik

I tried to create a really simple validation form using Formik. I followed their guide exactly with their example, but it just isn't working. I couldn't find a solution (Correct Me If I'm Wrong). Here's the error message I'm getting:

[image: Error messages]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple-form",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

**Formik Code**

```
"use client";

import {Formik} from "formik";

interface MyFormValues {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

export default function HomePage() {
    const initialValues: MyFormValues = { email: "", password: "" };

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        >
            {({ handleSubmit, handleChange, handleBlur, values }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name = "email"
                        placeholder = "email"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        name = "password"
                        placeholder = "password"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.password}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the Next.js App Router - pages are server components by default.

This problem occurs because you're trying to use a "client" oriented component inside a React server component. Formik relies on React hooks (we can see the `renderWithHooks` call in the backtrace).

Server Components doesn't support React Context, and that's why the error happens.

Try adding the `"use client";` statement at the top of your component.

[React client hook in Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-client-hook-in-server-component)

Comment: i did, but still happen

Comment: @xtreebug could you please provide a full example of how you use it in next.js?

Comment: sure, now the question updated

Comment: @xtreebug I just tested your sample on my test project and it works well. My dependencies: next 14.1.0, formik 2.4.5, react 18.2.0, react-dom 18.2.0